# Insert GeoIP City into html form

Tags: javascript

Searched and couldn't find an answer on this one. I am not much of a coder and know very little about javascript. Hoping someone here can help me out. I need to get the user's geoip city and then insert it as a value into a form. I have this script for getting the geoip city...

```
<script src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(geoip_city());</script>
```

I need that city to be put into the value part of the form

Any ideas on how to do this?

Form looks like this...

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom_City" id="city" value="NEED CITY IN HERE"></input>
```

Comment: Sorry that code should be <code><script src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">document.write(geoip_city());</script></code>

Comment: Please edit your question instead of putting code in comments. And what does the markup of your form look like?

Answer (score 2):

*After* the markup use this script:

```
document.getElementById("city").value = geoip_city();
```

Comment: I can't seem to get that to work. Can you please check the source on this page to see if I have it right? Thanks so much! http://luvintheair.com/datingus/index.html

Comment: @user2035590: It just works correctly, in Firebug's source pane I can see that `value` is changed to my city.

Answer (score 0):

You have given wrong path of live js it should be like
http://js.maxmind.com/js/geoip.js